# How can you say 'motor [and] rack and pinion'?

Tags: commas, lists

In a list, is the following correct?

> I'm using a micro-switch, motor and rack and pinion

Or should *rack and pinion* be treated as two entities:

> I'm using a micro-switch, motor, rack and pinion

[Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22motor%2C+rack+and+pinion%22) for `"motor, rack and pinion"` returns `43 results` - although only about a half are appropriate, while [Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22motor+and+rack+and+pinion%22) for `"motor and rack and pinion"` returns `2 results`

Which version should I use?

Comment: "Rack and pinion" is generally treated as a single entity.  However, this might be a place for the "Oxford" comma before *and*, to provide clarity:  "micro-switch, motor, and rack and pinion".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first example

> I'm using a micro-switch, motor and rack and pinion

is grammatically correct but there is slight potential for misinterpretation if the reader does not understand "rack and pinion". The second example gives the impression the rack and pinion are two separate items when (I assume) you want them to be thought of as one entity.

You could make it clearer, albeit more verbose, by saying:

> I'm using a micro-switch, a motor, and a rack and pinion

or, if the order is unimportant:

> I'm using a rack and pinion, micro-switch, and motor

Or, you could use rack-and-pinion as an adjective preceding a suitable noun, for example:

> I'm using a micro-switch, motor, and rack-and-pinion mechanism.